# Adding a google test framework to existing Xcode project

Tags: xcode, googletest

I use [this](https://github.com/google/googletest/tree/master/googletest) instruction and CMake tool. When I built XCode project created by CMake I had 2 .dylib files. When I add this tow libs and gtest_main.cc and gtest_all.cc in my existing project, compiler don't see #include "gtest/gtest.h" header.

How do I need to add google test to existing XCode project?

Answer (score 1):

So, I just set the build parameters of my project's test target, as in the examples for gtest, and it works.

Sorry for the stupid question

Comment: This is not a stupid question.